# How to bind 2 functions to a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an application where if I left click a button in a grid it changes the images to 1.jpg and when it is right clicked it changes to 2.jpg. I tried it several times but the image is not changing on right click.

This is how the grid looks like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3kks.jpg)

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

WIN = Tk()
WIN.geometry("280x660+300+10")

Button_Frame = Frame(WIN,width=399,height=100)
Button_Frame.pack()
Main = Frame(WIN,width=399,height=399)
Main.pack()

img1 = Image.open("2.jpg")
img1 = img1.resize((57, 57), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1) 

img2 = Image.open("3.jpg")
img2 = img2.resize((57, 57), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2) 

button_list = []
type_click = ""

for i in range(49):
    f1 = Frame(Main,width=40,height=40,bg="black")
    b = Button(f1, text = "",borderwidth=4,bg="white")
    button_list.append(b)

    def first(k):
        if type_click == "left":
            button_list[k].configure(image=photo1)
        elif type_click == "right":
            button_list[k].configure(image=photo2)

    def left(event):
        global type_click
        type_click = "left"
        print("left")
    def right(event):
        global type_click
        type_click = "right"    
        print("right")  

    b.configure(command=lambda k=i:first(k))
    b.bind("<Button-1>",left)
    b.bind("<Button-3>",right)
    f1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.grid_propagate(0)
    f1.grid(row = i//7, column = i%7)


   # b.bind("<Button-1>",lambda k=i:first(k))
    b.grid(sticky = "NWSE")
    
WIN.mainloop()
```

**Please tell me where am I going wrong**

Comment: Note that you'd be better off loading the two images *once*, as global variables (which would incidentally solve this problem) - there's absolutely no point in having 49 identical copies of an image in memory.

Comment: You mean to add the function "first" before the loop?

Comment: I mean, load the two images outside of any function or loop, near the top of your code.  Your two event handler functions would just refer to one of those two images, rather than loading a new copy each time from disk.

Comment: Oh there is some improvement but only one button is getting the image.

Comment: Where is the second image being loaded?

Comment: I have not added that yet

Comment: The image 1 is being added to only the button at the bottom right corner. Please help

Comment: Because the iteration ends, and thats the last item.

Comment: What you should be doing is, create an empty list and append the button to the list inside the loop, then something like `lst_name[i]` and will give refer to that button created in the loop and `lst_name[i].config(highlightbackground="black")` will be how you change it. Change your `command` to `command=lambda k=i:first(k)` then your function would be `def first(k):` and then inside the function it should be something like `lst_name[k].configure(image=photo)`

Comment: And also make sure to get rid of the `b.bind(..)`

Comment: Voting to reopen the Q as the problem is not only with the image created.

Comment: I am getting this `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Event`

Comment: I want the binding because I want the image to be diffferent based on left/right click

Comment: Although removing binding loads the image

Comment: please help me.

Comment: Its hard to explain on the comments, if the Q gets reopened ill add an answer :D

Comment: should I re-post question??

Comment: Im not sure about the `bind` though, it seems not possible with binding, but one button works

Comment: What does that mean for me?